# Partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've never deal with partial differential equation. My friend asked me to help him, I thought that it's like simple differential equation. But how can we find solution. 
$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{1+u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$ and $u(x,0) = \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$, $u(0,t) = e^{-t}$.

I found $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ at zero lines, but that doesn't give me anything. Also I thought about considering $dx$ and $dt$, but I don't know how to connect them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). It is also outlined in these [slides](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s14/m3357/lectures/lecture_1_21_slides.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately slides doesn't contain problem like mine, because there are no $a(x,t,u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + b(x,t,u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = c(x,t,u)$. May I ask? 
I've got : $\frac{dz}{0} = \frac{dx}{-1} = \frac{dt}{u + 1}$, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{1+u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

The system of ODEs is $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\frac{-1}{1+u}}=\frac{du}{0}\quad$

which is the same as what you wrote in comment : $\quad \frac{du}{0}=\frac{dx}{-1}=\frac{dt}{1+u}\quad$ which is correct.

A first family of characteristic curves comes from $du=0\quad\to\quad u=c_1$

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dx}{-1}=\frac{dt}{1+c_1}\quad\to\quad (1+c_1)x+t=c_2$

The general solution can be expressed on various equivalent implicit forms, for example:
$\Phi\left( u\:,\:(1+u)x+t\right)=0 \quad$ where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables, or

$u=f\left((1+u)x+t\right)\quad$ where $f$ is any differentiable function, or

$(1+u)x+t=g(u)\quad$ where $g$ is any differentiable function (inverse of $f$ ), or many equivalent others.

In any one of these equations, the arbitrary function $\Phi$, or $f$, or $g$, ... has to be determined according to the initial and boundary conditions.
This is often the difficult part of the job.

Unfortunately for you the condition $\quad u(x,0) = \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$, $u(0,t) = e^{-t}\quad$ is a difficult case.

If you successively apply each one of these conditions to the above general solution , for example $\quad u=f\left((1+u)x+t\right)\quad$, you found two different functions $f$ instead of the same function for both. This is apparently contradictory. In fact this means that they are two distinct domains separated by a "breaking" boundary. Then, a chock behavior can be described.

You mention that "I've never deal with partial differential equation. My friend asked me to help him". So, one can suppose that you and your friend are not used to deal with these kind of problems. Of course, one could straightforward give you the full solution. But, this would be of few help for you. It should be better to learn on regular course about cases of shock in solution and start with examples of PDEs with boundary and initial conditions leading to simpler cases of shock.